# Unable to write queuelinked into the file.dat

Tags: java

When I use my own queue linked, and try to write to file, it shows out the cannot save to file. But if I try to use Sorted List, it can be. I know the problem may appear on my own queue linked, but I can't find out what problem it is. At first, I thought it is because I don't have implements the serializable, but it comes to the same problem even I implements it.I can't think of a solution.

QueueLinkedIterator //this is iterator of the queue linked

`public class CLQIterator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements CLQIteratorInterface<T>, Serializable{...}`

QueueIteratorInterface //this is the interface of it

```
public interface CLQIteratorInterface <T extends Comparable <T>> extends CLQInterface<T>,Serializable {
    Iterator<T> getIterator();
    
}
```

AddVenue.java

```
public class AddVenuePage extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private Venue venue;
private CLQIteratorInterface <Venue> venueList = new CLQIterator<Venue>();

... //function

try {
          venueList.enQ(new Venue(venueId.getText(),venueName.getText()));
          File file = new File("venue.dat");
          // System.out.println("***TRACE: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
          ObjectOutputStream ooStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
          ooStream.writeObject(venueList);
          ooStream.close();
       
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot save to file", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Venue Has Successfully Added!", "Successful", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour], read [ask] and note that when asking about errors you should add all details you have (e.g. message, stacktrace etc.). You might now be asking yourself "but I don't have any stacktrace, I just get a message dialog". If so, you're at least tracking one error: never swallow the details of an exception you don't expect - think about all the reason saving to a file could fail with an `IOException`, how would you know what exactly went wrong?

Comment: One other thing: you might want to think about using try-with-resources so that the stream gets closed even in the case of an exception.